# Exercise 4.1 in Humphreys' BGG category O theory, about contravariant form.

Tags: modules, representation-theory, lie-algebras

The following modules are all over a finite dimensional simple complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

Let $M$ be a nonzero submodule of a Verma module $M(\lambda)$. If $M$ has a nondegenerate contravariant form, **prove that $M$ is the unique simple submodule of $M(\lambda)$.**

This is the definition of contravariant form:

If a symmetric bilinear form on a module $M$ satifies: $(x.a,b)=(a,\tau(x).b),\ \forall x\in\mathfrak{g}, a,b\in M$, where $\tau$ is Chevalley anti-involution, an anti-automorphism of order 2, then this form $(-,-)$ is called a ***contravariant form*** on $M$.

My thinking: There are a basic property about contravariant form: $(M_\lambda,M_\mu)=0$ if $\lambda\neq\mu$. Secondly, the Verma module $M(\lambda)$ has a unique simple submudule which is contained in any nonzero submodule of $M(\lambda)$. That means: Writing $L(\mu)$ be the unique simple module in $M(\lambda)$. (so, $L(\mu)\subseteq M$). If $M$ has a nondegenerate contravariant form, Then $L$ is contained in the conplement of any proper submodule of $M$. In another words, If $N\subsetneq M$, then $(N,L(\mu))=0$. However, there is a posibility: The sum of all proper submodules in $M$ is not equal to $M$. So, it still cannot lead to a contradiction.

Comment: You'll need to show at least some working or attempt at an answer, if only so that people answering your question can know where to pitch their answers.

Comment: @Joppy Sorry for not doing that. I just write some attempt of mine.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen why contravariant form has that peoperty? I mean, why the intersection of $N$ and $N^{\perp}$ has to be $0$?

Comment: You're right. I was speeding. It's been close to 30 years :-(

Comment: I don't think I ever studied category $O$ carefully. But in the few modules I recall using that had a simple socle and a non-degenerate contravariant form that simple submodule then also appeared in the head ($L$ vs. $M/L^\perp$), and hence multiplicity two. Is it known in the case of  a Verma module (in category $O$) that the unique simple submodule has multiplicity one as a compositiion factor?